# AVR controller, button issue

Tags: c, button, avr

I have problem, microcontroller simply doesnt register when i press button. As it didnt happened. Here is my code.

```
    #ifndef F_CPU   
    #define F_CPU 1000000UL         
    #endif

    #define bit_is_clear(byte, bit) (!(byte & (1 << bit)))

    #include <avr/io.h>
    #include <util/delay.h>
    #include <avr/interrupt.h>

    typedef enum { false, true } boolean;
    boolean clicked = false;

    int sigurno_pritisnut = 0;

    void pressed();
    void unpressed();

    int main(void)
{
    //LED OUTPUT
    DDRB |= (1 << PINB0) | (1 << PINB1) | (1 << PINB2);

    //LED LOW
    PORTB &= ~((1 << PINB0) | (1 << PINB1) | (1 << PINB2));

    //BUTTON INPUT
    DDRC &= ~(1 << PINC5);

    //BUTTON HIGH
    PORTC |= (1 << PINC5);

    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) 
    {
        if(bit_is_clear(PINC, PINC5)){
            sigurno_pritisnut++;
            if(sigurno_pritisnut > 400){
                clicked = !clicked;
                sigurno_pritisnut = 0;
            }
        }

        if(clicked){
            pressed();
        }else{
            unpressed();
        }

    }
}

void pressed(){
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB0);
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB1);
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB2);
    _delay_ms(500);
    sigurno_pritisnut = 0;
}

void unpressed(){
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB0);
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB0);
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB1);
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB1);
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB2);
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB ^= (1 << PINB2);

}
```

...................................................................
I have tried with other buttons, tried with other pins but nothing. 
...................................................................

Comment: first of all  `PORTB &= ~(1 << PINB0) & ~(1 << PINB1) & ~(1 << PINB2);` PORTB &= ~((1 << PINB0) | (1 << PINB1) | (1 << PINB2));` etc etc

Comment: Question: When `bit_is_clear` is true, does that mean "button pressed" ?

Comment: @4386427 yes it does

Comment: Are you sure the button is connected right? Between PC5 and "GND"? Also you may want to set `sigurno_pritisnut = 0` at `else` branch of `if(bit_is_clear(PINC, PINC5)){ ...`

Answer (score 1):

The problem seem to be your delay statements. In both `pressed` and `unpressed` you wait 3 x 500ms.

In the loop you want to see `bit_is_clear` 400 times before changing `clicked`.

So it seems that `bit_is_clear` must be true in 600 seconds before you change `clicked`.

Notice that this

```
    if(clicked){
        pressed();
    }else if(!clicked){
        unpressed();
    }
```

is the same as

```
    if(clicked){
        pressed();
    }else
        unpressed();
    }
```

so in every loop you'll enter one of them.

Further it seems strange that you don't an `else` here:

```
    if(bit_is_clear(PINC, PINC5)){
        sigurno_pritisnut++;
        if(sigurno_pritisnut > 500){
            clicked = !clicked;
            sigurno_pritisnut = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // ... don't you need some code here?
    }
```

So button works like this

`bit_is_clear` == true means **pressed**

`bit_is_clear` == false means **released**

you'll need something like:

```
while (1) 
{
    while (1)  // Loop until a state is changed
    {
        if(bit_is_clear(PINC, PINC5))
        {
             // pressed
             if (clicked)
             {
                 // Same state so just continue...
                 sigurno_pritisnut = 0;
                 continue;
             }
             sigurno_pritisnut++;
             if(sigurno_pritisnut > 400){
                 clicked = 1;
                 sigurno_pritisnut = 0;

                 // State change - break out
                 break;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             // released
             if (!clicked)
             {
                 sigurno_pritisnut = 0;
                 continue;
             }
             sigurno_pritisnut++;
             if(sigurno_pritisnut > 400){
                 clicked = 0;
                 sigurno_pritisnut = 0;
                 break;
             }
         }
    }

    if(clicked){
        pressed();
    }else{
        unpressed();
    }

}
```

In this way you only call `pressed` / `unpressed` when something new has happened.

Comment: i have changed but it seems to be the same

Comment: @user7585238 I've pasted it but now led wont light up.

Comment: @user7585238 Have you checked that you get into the `pressed` function?

Comment: @user7585238  yes  i did

Comment: @user7585238  thank you very much,  it seems that breadboard is  losing contact

Comment: @user7585238 Well, your `unpressed` function seem to toggle the port bits but will end up with the port being the same. Maybe make it more simple and only toggle the bits once

Comment: I did this and it works.
if(bit_is_clear(PINC,5)){
   _delay_ms(20);
   if(bit_is_clear(PINC,5)){
    clicked = !clicked;
   }
  }

Thank you again